# Date command returns same month for today's date plus one or two months

Tags: shell

Today is 2016-01-31. When I use

```
date -d 'next month' +"%d"
```

I expect it to return `02`, and I got `02`. But observe:

```
[/bazar]$date +"%Y%m%d"
20160131
[/bazar]$date -d '+1 month' +"%Y%m"
201603
[/home/bazar]$date -d '+2 month' +"%Y%m"
201603
[/home/bazar]$date -d '+3 month' +"%Y%m"
201605
```

Why do `+1 month` and `+2 month` both return `201603`?

Comment: So you got your expected output, what exactly is the problem? Please edit your question to clearly indicate the problem.  What output were you expecting?  What output did you receive?

Comment: I think the question should read `expect it will output 02, actually I got 03`. I tried locally on my system, same result. Sort of unexpected, couldn't find reasonable documentation for this behavior.

Comment: that's right,thank u

Comment: Use `%Y%m%d` for all the commands and see what it prints.

Comment: date -d '+1 month' +"%Y%m%d"   ------------>20160302

Answer (score 1):

date takes your request very literally and tries to use a date of 31st February(Since the date given by you is 31st January )and since that doesn't exist it moves to the month of next day so does it return 03 for (+1 month).

Comment: at 20160201 execute  `date -d '-1 month' +"%Y%m%d"` output 20160101, it's right?